# Как реализовать счетчик нажатий на инлайн кнопку?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Не могу реализовать этот счетчик, после того как отправилась фотка в канал с описанием и двумя кнопками, я по ней нажимаю, и ничего не происходит, возможно хендлер не ловит, или нужно чтобы начинался полинг, но сообщения в канал отправляются пока не наступит полинг, когда он начнется сообщения не отправляется, не знаю как исправить все это, очень был бы рад, если бы кто-то помог!!!

```
    import asyncio

from asyncio.log import logger
from os import listdir

from aiogram import types
from aiogram.types import InputFile
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hlink

from config import channels
from keyboards.good_or_bad import good_or_bad_keyboard
from loader import bot, dp
from utils.notify_admins import on_startup_notify
import datetime


async def on_startup(dp):
    await on_startup_notify(dp)


async def send_photo(chat_id: int, photo: InputFile, caption: str):
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo, caption)


# Переменные для итерации фото
mypath = "images"
photos = list()
formats = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']
savedSet = set()

# Переменные для ссылки на канал
one = '9x16 - Name Channel'
two = 't.me/link_on_channel'
three = '@name_channel'
url = two

# Переменные для итерации времени
time_3 = str(datetime.time(hour=11, minute=39))
time_3 = time_3[:-3]
time_5 = str(datetime.time(hour=11, minute=40))
time_5 = time_5[:-3]
time_7 = str(datetime.time(hour=11, minute=41))
time_7 = time_7[:-3]


# Переменные для итерации реакций

async def main(dp):

    async def generator_1(param):
        param += 1
        return param

    x_global = 0
    y_global = 0
    while True:
        @dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='good')
        async def good_reaction(call: types.CallbackQuery):
            await call.answer('Вам понравилась публикация')
            x_local = 0
            x_local = x_global
            await generator_1(param=x_local)

        @dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='bad')
        async def bad_reaction(call: types.CallbackQuery):
            await call.answer('Вам не понравилась публикация')
            y_local = 0
            y_local = y_global
            await generator_1(param=y_local)

        now_global = datetime.datetime.now()
        now_global = str(now_global.time())
        now_global = now_global.split('.')[0]
        now_global = now_global[:-3]
        if now_global == time_3:
            for i in formats:
                for j in filter(lambda x: x.endswith(i), listdir(mypath)):
                    photos.append(j)
            for i in photos:
                now_local = datetime.datetime.now()
                now_local = str(now_local.time())
                now_local = now_local.split('.')[0]
                now_local = now_local[:-3]
                if now_local == time_3 or time_5 or time_7:
                    with open(f"{mypath}/{i}", 'rb') as photo:
                        print(f'Сейчас {now_local}')
                        print('Отправляю фото')
                        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=channels, photo=photo, caption=f'{hlink(one, url=two)}\n'
                                                                                       f'{hlink(two, url=two)}\n'
                                                                                       f'{hlink(three, url=two)}',
                                                reply_markup=good_or_bad_keyboard)

                        @dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='good')
                        async def good_reaction(call: types.CallbackQuery):
                            await call.answer('Вам понравилась публикация')
                            x_local = 0
                            x_local = x_global
                            await generator_1(param=x_local)

                        @dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='bad')
                        async def bad_reaction(call: types.CallbackQuery):
                            await call.answer('Вам не понравилась публикация')
                            y_local = 0
                            y_local = y_global
                            await generator_1(param=y_local)
                    await asyncio.sleep(60)
                    if now_local == time_7:
                        print('Остановка')
                        await asyncio.sleep(120)
        else:
            pass
        try:
            await dp.start_polling()
        finally:
            await dp.storage.close()
            await dp.storage.wait_closed()
            await bot.session.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main(dp))
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        logger.error("Bot stopped!")
```

Comment: Тут переделывать нужно 90 процентов кода

Comment: А зачем ты запускаешь цикл while и в нем обрабатываешь  пишешь функции, и callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс для установки InlineKeyboard

В кнопке устанавливаем  `callback_data="InlineKeyboardDay"`

```
class TrainingCalendar:
    """
    async Класс для создания InlineKeyboard в виде календаря

    Args:
            month (int): Месяц, по умолчанию текщий. Defaults to None.
            year (int): Год, по умолчанию текщий. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
            InlineKeyboardMarkup: возвращает клавиатуру в виде календаря
    """

    def __init__(self, month: int = None, year: int = None) -> None:
        dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not month:
            month = dt_now.month
        if not year:
            year = dt_now.year
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.day_of_week = ["Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вс"]

    async def creating_calendar_list(self) -> list:
        """
        Создает список календаря

        Returns:
            list: [['month int(year)'],[days..],[days..],[days..],[days..],[days..],[days..]]
        """
        try:
            calendar_list = calendar.month(self.year, self.month, 2, 1).split()
            month_and_year = ' '.join(calendar_list[:2])
            list_of_days = calendar.monthcalendar(self.year, self.month)
            new_calendar_list = list_of_days
            new_calendar_list.insert(0, [month_and_year])
            return new_calendar_list
        except IndexError as errore:
            logger.error(f"\n{errore}\nПередан месяц: {self.month}.\
                \nМесяц не может быть больше 12")
        except TypeError as errore:
            logger.error(f"\n{errore}\nМесяц и год не могут быть строкой: \
                 \n {self.month}: {type(self.month)}\n \
                 {self.year}: {type(self.year)}")

    async def _add_month_and_year_to_the_keyboard(self, keyboar: InlineKeyboardMarkup,
                                                  month_and_year: list) -> None:
        """
        Добавляем месяц и год а так же кнопку назад и вперед
        """
        keyboar_list = [InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='< ',
            callback_data="InlineKeyboardBack"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=''.join(month_and_year),
            callback_data="InlineKeyboardNone"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=' >',
            callback_data="InlineKeyboardNext")]
        keyboar.row(*keyboar_list)

    async def _add_days_of_the_week_to_the_keyboard(self, keyboar: InlineKeyboardMarkup) -> None:
        """
        Добавляем дни недели
        """
        button_list = []
        for i in self.day_of_week:
            button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(
                text=i,
                callback_data="InlineKeyboardNone"))
        keyboar.row(*button_list)

    async def _add_days_to_the_keyboard(self, keyboar: InlineKeyboardMarkup,
                                        days_list: list) -> None:
        """
        Добавляем дни 
        """
        for cildren in days_list:
            button_list = []
            for day in cildren:
                if day == 0:
                    day = " "
                Notebook_data = await Notebook.getting_data_from_json(f"{day}.{self.month}.{self.year}")
                if Notebook_data is not None and Notebook_data.get("workout") == True:
                    button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text=str(day) + "✅", callback_data="InlineKeyboardDay"))
                else:
                    button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(
                        text=str(day), callback_data="InlineKeyboardDay"))
            keyboar.row(*button_list)

    async def _create_calendar_keyboard(self) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
        if calendar_list := await self.creating_calendar_list():
            # Создаем клавиатуру
            keyboar = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=7)
            # Добавляем месяц и год
            await self._add_month_and_year_to_the_keyboard(keyboar, calendar_list[0])
            # Добавляем дни недели
            await self._add_days_of_the_week_to_the_keyboard(keyboar)
            # Добавляем дни
            await self._add_days_to_the_keyboard(keyboar, calendar_list[1:])
            return keyboar

    async def get_calendar_keyboard(self) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
        """
        Публичный метод для получения клавиатуры

        Returns:
            InlineKeyboardMarkup: клавиатура в виде календаря
        """
        if keyboar := await self._create_calendar_keyboard():
            return keyboar
```

После чего мы ловим InlineKeyboardDay (callback_data="InlineKeyboardDay")

```
@dispatcher.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data and 'InlineKeyboardDay' in c.data)
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    """
    Обрабатываем CallbackQuery
    """
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    callback_data = callback_query.data
    message = json.loads(callback_query.as_json())
    for i in message["message"]["reply_markup"]["inline_keyboard"]:
        for j in i:
            if j["callback_data"] == callback_data:
                CallbackDataDict.update({message["from"]["id"]: {callback_data: j}})
                pass
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*["✅Добавить тренировку", "❌Отменить тренировку"])
    keyboard.add(*["✅Добавить парметры тела", "Показать парметры тела"])
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text="Выберите команду", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

А ты качестве callback_data ловишь просто текст а не callback `@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='good')`

Попробуй так `@dispatcher.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data and 'good' in c.data)`